# "Fraction" type appears along with fractions in my printed List

Tags: python

I am using Python and fractions.Fraction()

I have a list of fractions that I want printed to look like this:

```
a = Fraction(0.25)
b = Fraction(1,3)
...
l = [a,b,...]
print(l)
>>>[1/4 , 1/3,...]
```

but instead I get:

```
a = Fraction(0.25)
b = Fraction(1,3)
...
l = [a,b,...]
print(l)
>>>[Fraction(1,4), Fraction(1,3),...]
```

I know I can get around this by iterating over the list I have and printing each element individually, but I wanted to know if there was an easier built in way before trying to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
from fractions import *
a = Fraction(0.25)
b = Fraction(1,3)
l = [a,b]
print(list(map(lambda x :x.__str__(),l)))
```

this invokes the str function of Fraction class, passing the objects a,b.
or,

```
map(str,l)
```

also works as the same.

Comment: Why would you use `lambda x: x.__str__()` instead of `str` in the `map`? It does the same thing

Comment: @asdf101, it is the same thing, as I mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 4):

Before you print you can invoke `str` on each fraction to get the desired form:

```py
>>> your_list = [Fraction(0.25), Fraction(1,3)]

>>> out_list = [str(frac) for frac in your_list]

>>> print(out_list)
['1/4', '1/3']
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining `fractionslist` as `[Fraction(3, 4)] * 10`, I don't think it can get any shorter and more readable than this:

```py
>>> print(*fractionslist)
3/4 3/4 3/4 3/4 3/4 3/4 3/4 3/4 3/4 3/4
```

The asterisk unpacks the values in `fractionslist`, and `print` automatically converts the values to string.

A variant on this, but separated by commas:

```py
>>> print(*fractionslist, sep = ", ")
3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4
```

You can also map all the items in the list to `str`, then join them:

```py
>>> print(", ".join(map(str, fractionslist)))
3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4
```

Or you can print them individually like you pointed out but without newlines (note that it does put a space at the end):

```py
>>> for fraction in fractionslist: print(fraction, end=" ")
3/4 3/4 3/4 3/4 3/4 3/4 3/4 3/4 3/4 3/4
```

Answer (score 1):

Given `a=Fraction(3,7)`, `str(a)` should return `'3/7'`

Then printing a list of fractions is probably easiest and most attractive by unpacking a map:

```py
LF = [Fraction(a*2+1, a*2+5) for a in range(1,21)]
print(*map(str,LF), sep=", ")
```

gives

```
3/7, 5/9, 7/11, 9/13, 11/15, 13/17, 15/19, 17/21, 19/23, 21/25, 23/27, 25/29, 27/31, 
29/33, 31/35, 33/37, 35/39, 37/41, 39/43, 41/45
```